# Restoring default file permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I know they say that given root access, someone will eventually type before they think and fubar their machine, and I just did.

I did a recursive chmod changing everything to 775 thinking I was in a sub directory, but alas, I was in /. Is there any magical way to undo this, or at the very least, get a list of default directory permissions and manually restore them?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/40025/how-do-i-recover-a-rhel-4-3-server-from-bad-permissions-set-over-the-entire-files

Comment: The "real" way is to restore from backup. Assuming you don't have backups, have a look at that question-- there are some ideas that can get you most of the way there, depending on what distro you're running, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no undo. Beyond installing a box with similar unix, and scripting something to check everything permissions, I don't believe there's a list of default permissions either. Not very helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Accepting this answer because, well, "There's no undo". I just re-installed the server (all important files were backed up but not generic system files and such). The other RPM-based solutions presented sound nice but this is Debian =/

Answer (score 4):

I have exact same problem.

```
rpm -a --setperms
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: What value does this offer over the answers from six years ago?

Answer (score 3):

If your distribution is rpm based, the rpm database contains permission information. The command

```
rpm --setperms {packagename}
```

should reset the permission for the given package.

Comment: you can simply do : 
 rpm -a --setperms
on rpm based distros in order to restore most of permissions (run it as root)

Answer (score 0):

To amend the "rpm --setperms" information, that will allow you to fix the permissions of all files and directories which were installed as RPM packages.  It will *NOT* fix the permissions of files that were installed without using RPM.

You can get a list of all the installed packages by doing "rpm -qa", for use in feeding to the "rpm --setperms".  You can also use "rpm -Va | less" to have RPM do an integrity check on all installed files and directories to allow you to do more fine-grained adjusting of permissions -- it will report if the file contents, modes, and times have changed, and whether the file is a configuration file or not.

Sean