# Reset OpenSUSE file permissions across system

Tags: opensuse

I was wondering if there is a set of commands that you can run to reset file permissions to default. A bunch of directories/files got their permissions changed on my server due to me copying and pasting a shell script without looking closer into what it was actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way doing this except for resetting the packages contents rights.

You could try :

```
rpm --setperms {packagename}
```

But it wont probably affect all LSB directories.

Comment: You can find more info here http://serverfault.com/questions/40025/how-do-i-recover-a-rhel-4-3-server-from-bad-permissions-set-over-the-entire-file

Comment: I found this site: http://www.novell.com/communities/node/5877/reset-your-sleopensuse-linux-default-file-system-permissions that seems like it should do the trick... is this correct?

Comment: I would not use it without previous verification because it's not supported by community and post is 4 years old.